# Best Way to Add Sublist in EF

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4

My database model has the following

Users(table) related to orders(table) related to order line items(table)

I would like to have a navigational property for order line items mapped to the user, however I  don't want to have to setup a user_id and foreign key on the order line items table - is there a way I can do this via EF - i'd rather just somehow connect it via the fact that the user is tied to the order table - and that assumes that the user is tied to all those order line items?

I'm using EF v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see why you wouldn't want the foreign key, but If you go into the model viewer and right click  on the entity name you can choose add-> association to manually add one in.

Comment: If i add the foriegn keys then I need to add the user id to the order_line_item table and a thru the code and tons of places, just lots of work that kind of scares me.. lol - anyways, i've added a new navigation property however its only allowing me to choose from keys already defined in the db, after adding the navigation property i'm not really sure how to tie it all together

Comment: dont choose add -> navigation propery. add an association, it brings up a wizard that does it all for you

Comment: Hi KMCC049, i've done the association however it appears that its unable to work properly as i'm receiving error messages, i believe it may be because the user id table doesn't exist in the order_line_items table, but in the orders table

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a partial class for the OrderLine entity and add a property called User.  Implement the user property to automatically return the user object via the Order entity.

For example (vb):

```
Partial Public Class OrderLine

    Public Readonly Property User As User
        Get
            Return Me.Order.User
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: I want to actually show the order line items by user, so it would be a partial class on the User, i've tried this (in c# ) however i can't seem to access the get { return this.orders_assigned.order_line_items; } -> i can't seem to access the orders_assigned navigation property from the partial user class